# retrieve data from mysql using php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, response

I have a menu, it contains multiple items, each menu item will retrieve data from the database.
I want to do it without the page refresh, I want like an area that will change when the user clicks on the menu link.
How should I send data to the php script and how should I get it from there and preview it on the page?
If you can send me any information, references or examples that will be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by reading some of the documentation from the jQuery website:
http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

This might also be of interest to you: 
http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/ajax-jquery

Comment: It may also help to learn how ajax/dom manipulation works apart from jQuery. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/views/web/libraryview.jsp?search_by=Mastering+Ajax This link if you have a lot of time for reading might help explain things better